# C# How to make a property assignment independent in a loop

Tags: c#, properties

I'm not sure if my title is clear or specific enough but here is what I'm trying to do.

I have a new class

```
public class Segments
    {            
        public List<double> List1 { get; set; }
        public List<double> List2 { get; set; } 
        public List<double> List3 { get; set; } 
        public List<double> List4 { get; set; } 
    }

public static void SplitSegments(CsvClass longList, List<Segments> segments)
    {
        Segments tempSegments = new Segments();
        List<double> list1 = new List<double>();
        List<double> list2 = new List<double>();
        List<double> list3 = new List<double>();
        List<double> list4 = new List<double>();

        // Nested For loop that goes through a longList with its own properties.
        // Below is a flag for when to split that longList.properties into segments

        if (flag == true)
        {
             //The lists are now complete for the first segment.
             list1.Add(longList.one[i]);
             list2.Add(longList.two[i]);
             list3.Add(longList.three[i]);
             list4.Add(longList.four[i]);

             //created a copy of the class properties
             tempSegments.List1 = new List<double>(list1);
             tempSegments.List2 = new List<double>(list2);
             tempSegments.List3 = new List<double>(list3);
             tempSegments.List4 = new List<double>(list4);

             //Add to List<Segments>
             segments.Add(tempSegments)

             //Clear lists in order to move on to creating next segment of the longList.
             list1.Clear();
             list2.Clear();
             list3.Clear();
             list4.Clear();
             break;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is when the new segment is created and added to the `List<Segments>`, all the segments become the same exact copy of the new segment.

I suppose the Lists in the class still reference the same objects as the lists. My question is how do I make it so that when the new segments are added to the `List<Segments>`, they don't erase the old segments?

Comment: Maybe it's just because it's late... but that is by far one of the most confusing code bits I've read in a while. What's `longList` from? EDIT: And is this the actual code? I see a `break`, but I don't see a loop for it to break from...

Comment: @ChrisSinclair That's what I thought at first too. Read the two-line comment a few more times.

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry, I knew it would be confusing. The longList is a csv file that I read in with the individual columns as properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the line

```
Segments tempSegments = new Segments();
```

into the body of the loop, probably right within the `if` clause `if (flag == true)`. This would create a new segment on each iteration.

The whole part of code would look like:

```
    if (flag == true)
    {
         Segments tempSegments = new Segments();
         //The lists are now complete for the first segment.
         list1.Add(longList.one[i]);
         list2.Add(longList.two[i]);
         list3.Add(longList.three[i]);
         list4.Add(longList.four[i]);

         //created a copy of the class properties
         tempSegments.List1 = new List<double>(list1);
         tempSegments.List2 = new List<double>(list2);
         tempSegments.List3 = new List<double>(list3);
         tempSegments.List4 = new List<double>(list4);

         //Add to List<Segments>
         segments.Add(tempSegments)

         //Clear lists...
         list1.Clear();
         list2.Clear();
         list3.Clear();
         list4.Clear();
         break;
    }
```

Comment: THANK YOU. I knew it was something simple, I just couldn't wrap my head around it. That's the solution and the `List<Segments>` is updating correctly now. Thanks again!!

Comment: @Freddy you're welcome. The code you had simply added one and the same instance of `Segements` into the `segments` list. While you needed to create each time a new one.

Answer (score 0):

```
//created a copy of the class properties
tempSegments = new Segments();  // otherwise you are just changing the properties on a single obj and adding that obj many times to your list.
tempSegments.List1 = new List<double>(list1);
tempSegments.List2 = new List<double>(list2);
tempSegments.List3 = new List<double>(list3);
tempSegments.List4 = new List<double>(list4);
```